# Linear mixed effects vs. Repeated Measures

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have 46 replicate trees I sampled in a 2 year study.
My objective is: To estimate the proportion of variation among-trees w/in year, and proportion variation due to among year and tree interaction.

Response: 12, 15, 32, 42, 13, 26, 10, 15

Year: A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B,

Tree: 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4

The above is an example of my dataset

I planned on running a repeated measures ANOVA (because I sampled the same tree in 2 years) but because circularity was violated, I decided to go with a mixed effects model. With trees as random and year as fixed. I'm then running a variance components analysis.

Q1. Is the Mixed Effect Model a good choice to answer my initial questions?

My model is this (in R code):

```
lme <- lme(response ~ year, random=~1|tree/year, df)
```

Also, I am not getting p-values for the interaction term after running Linear Mixed Effects Model (nor do I when I run a normal aov (2 way ANOVA) model using tree*year as a factor.)

Q2. A variance component analysis says that most of the variation (55%) is due to year and tree interaction. So why am I not getting the p-values for the interaction term?

Comment: You cannot violate circularity with only two levels of the repeated measure.

Comment: If you are using R, install lmertest before. It will then give p values for an lme